# grep with multiple word matches in multiple files

Tags: grep

I have tomcat access logs in multiple files.
All the files are under the same directory. I am in MacOS.

Like this in one of the files:

```
POST /context HTTP/1.1 200 266 20 <url>.com
GET /context1 HTTP/1.1 200 266 20 <url>.in
POST /context2 HTTP/1.1 200 266 20 <url>.de
```

Now I want to grep/search and print the lines which matches with "context" and ".com".

This has to be done over the multiple files in the directory.

I tried this `grep "/context" . | grep ".com"` but this does not work over a directory.

Comment: `grep -i '/context .*\.com' *.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `.com` always follows `/context`, try

```
grep 'context.*\.com' *
```

(or a better wildcard if you have other files; maybe try `tomcat*.log` instead of `*`?)

If the patterns could be in any order, you could use

```sh
grep -E 'context.*\.com|\.com.*context' *
```

(The `-E` option switches to a different regex dialect which lets you use `|` for "or". You could also remove the `-E` option and use `\|` but I think this is clumsy and confusing.)

... or switch to Awk.

```sh
awk '/context/ && /\.com/' *
```

Comment: thanks a lot...any way to print unique lines...as the logs will have many duplicate lines

Comment: Trivially, pipe to `| sort -u`. This is also simple to do natively in Awk; it's roughly module 2 or 3 in any intro to Awk. If you can't figure it out, ask a new question with your _actual_ requirements.